# sorting 12 month (1-12) with given start month

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem to find an algorithm to sort a table by month column starting at any given value.

For example this table:

```
month | sales
1     | 621,12
2     | ...    
3     | ....
4     |
5     |
6     |
7     |
8     |
9     |
10    |
11    |
12    |
```

Let's say i have starting month=5  - then i want to get:

```
month | sales
5     | 
6     |    
7     |
8     |
9     |
10    |
11    |
12    |
1     | 621,12
2     | ...
3     | ....
4     |
```

the base-table ALWAYS has 12 records in my case (month value is always 1-12).

would be nice if anyone has an idea how to achieve this with SQL

Thank you!

Comment: Sorting by the year-month makes this a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the modulus operator:

```
order by (month + 12 - 5) % 12
```

Or with a `case`:

```
order by (case when month > 5 then 1 else 2 end),
         month
```

Comment: (month + 12 - 5) % 12 = (month - 5) % 12

Comment: thanks a lot - that's exactly what i was look for :)